# Integrating with HCubature in julia

Tags: julia, numerical-integration

I have a problem.
Let's say we have a function depending on 3 variables:
f(x,y,z) = x+y+z
I want to integrate it with respect to x and y and leave z fixed. We can take z = 0 or whatever.

I've tried simply:

```
using HCubature

f(x,y,z) = x+y+z

result = hcubature((x,y)->f(x,y,0),(0,0),(1,1))
```

but it gives an error

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching (::var"#1#2")(::StaticArraysCore.SVector{2, Float64})
Closest candidates are:
  (::var"#1#2")(::Any, ::Any) at ~/magisterka/sandbox.jl:5
Stacktrace:
 [1] (::HCubature.GenzMalik{2, Float64})(f::var"#1#2", a::StaticArraysCore.SVector{2, Float64}, b::StaticArraysCore.SVector{2, Float64}, norm::typeof(LinearAlgebra.norm))
   @ HCubature ~/.julia/packages/HCubature/QvyJW/src/genz-malik.jl:121
 [2] hcubature_(f::var"#1#2", a::StaticArraysCore.SVector{2, Float64}, b::StaticArraysCore.SVector{2, Float64}, norm::typeof(LinearAlgebra.norm), rtol_::Int64, atol::Int64, maxevals::Int64, initdiv::Int64)
   @ HCubature ~/.julia/packages/HCubature/QvyJW/src/HCubature.jl:61
 [3] hcubature_(f::Function, a::Tuple{Int64, Int64}, b::Tuple{Int64, Int64}, norm::Function, rtol::Int64, atol::Int64, maxevals::Int64, initdiv::Int64)
   @ HCubature ~/.julia/packages/HCubature/QvyJW/src/HCubature.jl:132
 [4] hcubature(f::var"#1#2", a::Tuple{Int64, Int64}, b::Tuple{Int64, Int64}; norm::Function, rtol::Int64, atol::Int64, maxevals::Int64, initdiv::Int64)
   @ HCubature ~/.julia/packages/HCubature/QvyJW/src/HCubature.jl:179
 [5] hcubature(f::var"#1#2", a::Tuple{Int64, Int64}, b::Tuple{Int64, Int64})
   @ HCubature ~/.julia/packages/HCubature/QvyJW/src/HCubature.jl:179
 [6] top-level scope
   @ ~/magisterka/sandbox.jl:5
```

How can I integrate f(x,y,z) with fixed z?
I still try to understand HCubature package so I will be thankful for any help

Answer (score 0):

The integrand in HCubature takes a single vector as an argument, not multiple arguments `(x,y)`.  This works for your example:

```
julia> using HCubature

julia> f(x,y,z) = x+y+z;

julia> hcubature(r->f(r[1],r[2],0), (0,0), (1,1))
(1.0, 0.0)
```